# MongoDB C# unable to connect to database: Unable to create an authenticator

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

While setting up my new environment with a freshly deployed MongoDB container with authentication enabled, I ran into this exception: `"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create an authenticator."`

In my case I'm using a connection string like this example: `mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT`. This string works perfectly fine in MongoDB Compass but not inside my .NET 6.0 application.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code of C# MongoDB driver in [MongoCredential.cs#L469](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCredential.cs#L469), you see this exception gets thrown while checking the auth mechanism.

After specifying the exact auth mechanism in the connection string, all exceptions are gone!

example: `mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:27017/?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256`

Hope anyone else googeling around will find my answer helpful!

happy coding.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the authMechanism=DEFAULT parameter from the connection string

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33581823)

Comment: Underrated answer

Answer (score 3):

For me this just changed the exception to `unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism scram-sha-256`

After some trial and error I got it working by changing the connection string to:

`mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:27017/?authSource=admin`

I have no idea why this was needed as the default and SCRAM-SHA-256 connectionstrings works fine in other contexts...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and found out that usernames that include `_` just don't want to work with the C# driver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).